# How to update/delete record using seed_fu gem in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, seed

My seed_fu gem is working fine.But does not know how to update/delete an record.My table is as follows..,

```
1|user1|42|2012-02-17 12:22:00.581111|2012-02-17 12:22:00.581111
2|user2|24|2012-02-17 12:22:00.603150|2012-02-17 12:22:00.603150
```

I'm having two records .I want to update record2 (i.e,the age as 12).I expect that the record2 to be updated.
Instead I'm getting the new updated record as follows.,

```
1|user1|42|2012-02-17 12:22:00.581111|2012-02-17 12:22:00.581111
2|user2|24|2012-02-17 12:22:00.603150|2012-02-17 12:22:00.603150
3|user2|12|2012-02-17 12:40:32.577283|2012-02-17 12:40:32.577283
```

Also I want to know how to delete a record using seed-fu gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seed-fu gem is use only to insert, You can't update or delete with it. Use ActiveRecord to do that.

```
User.find(2).update_attributes!({:age -> 12})
User.find(3).destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually (as I found to my chagrin), if you specify the id in the seed_fu file and the id exists, that record will be overwritten. (I generated a seed_fu fill with over 200 records but forgot to change the id from 1 - wound up with one record. *sigh*)